# How to change value in Streambuilder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want the value "roomId" in my stream to change everytime the user presses the button (it calls my function which returns a different value everytime).

The problem is, that I cannot call setState inside my Button, because I receiver an error then. How can I change the value of roomId, so that my stream listens to a different roomId everytime the user presses the button?

```
    class _RandomMatchScreenState extends State<RandomMatchScreen> {
  String uid = AuthService().getUserId();
  String roomId = "a";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFffd04f),
      // create streambuilder and change roomId to roomId defined after button is pressed
      body: StreamBuilder<Room>(
          stream: getRoomStream(roomId),
          builder: (context, roomSnapshot) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      String newRoomId = await connectRoom(uid);
                      setState(() {
                        roomId = newRoomId;
                      });
                      // setState of roomId so StreamBuilder can listen to right room
                      print("roomId: $roomId");

                      // get roomSnapshot and check if uid1 and uid2 are not empty

                      // If room uid1 and uid2 are not equal to "" then navigate to chat screen
                      if (roomSnapshot.hasData) {
                        roomSnapshot.data!.userId1 != "" &&
                                roomSnapshot.data!.userId2 != ""
                            ? print("both users are in room")
                            : print("waiting for other user");
                      } else {
                        print("no data");
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Connect")),
```

Comment: It should be possible to call `setState` in the `onPressed` of your button. Wht error do you get when you do so?

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() callback argument returned a Future.
E/flutter ( 9947): The setState() method on _RandomMatchScreenState#b8321 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
E/flutter ( 9947): Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().

Comment: This is the error I get (I need to set the setState to async, otherwise the code won't compile)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code where you call `setState` in `onPressed` and the error message.

Comment: I just updated the code. Even though I call setState, it apparently is not working. My console prints "no data" which basically means my roomId in the Stream is not updated, which causes my snapshot to return no data. Any idea why, Frank?

Comment: Please put the description of what isn't working in the question too. Folks shouldn't have to crawl comments to find what print output you get from the code in the question. You should probably also print the data itself, as right now you also print `no data` when the user IDs don't match.